# Get Nested List value and add it to button text

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter I've Created a nested list with questions and answers like this

```
  var questions = [
    {
      'question': '1+1',
      'answer': [
        {'text': 2,'correct':1},
        {'text': 3,'correct':0},
        {'text': 4,'correct':0},
        {'text': 5,'correct':0}
      ]
    },
    {
      'question': '1+4',
      'answer': [
        {'text': 2,'correct':0},
        {'text': 3,'correct':0},
        {'text': 4,'correct':0},
        {'text': 5,'correct':1}
      ]
    },
    {
      'question': '1+7',
      'answer': [
        {'text': 7,'correct':0},
        {'text': 8,'correct':1},
        {'text': 9,'correct':0},
        {'text': 10,'correct':0}
      ]
    },
  ];
```

Now I want to get the value of answer[0] or answer[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfUul.jpg) and add that value to the RaisedButton text
Or even if it's a possibility to use for loop to generate a button for each answer

Thanks in advance.

I've tried

```
for ( var i in questions ) RaisedButton(onPressed: (){},child: Text((i['answer'].toString())),)
```

but I get it like this

[image]

Comment: why not, its possible. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I will edit my question and add it

Comment: I get like the image

Comment: Added an answer, please check and response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `questions` is a `List` and that list again contains a `List` which is `i['answer']` and that contains `Map`.

First you have to iterate over `List` (below code snippet I used `ListView`, if the list is not long you can use `for` or `map`). Next you have to again iterate because it contains a `List` also (for this I used for loop but you can use `map()` also). Then to get the question text you can use the key, which is `text`:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: questions.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        final quest = questions[index]['answer'];
        return Row(
          children: [
            for (final q in quest)
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  print(q["correct"] == 1);
                },
                child: Text(q["text"].toString() ?? ""),
              )
          ],
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Try using [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/212d4a874dd25c6324da5a7e14c6649a).

Comment: now it says ``` ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Comment: @eraufi I provided an link please refer that and let me know.https://dartpad.dartlang.org/212d4a874dd25c6324da5a7e14c6649a

Comment: @eraufi I updated the answer again to show how to access correct answer. Please refer.

Comment: @eraufi Glad to help you Eraufi. Happy coding!

Comment: @Blasanka i am stucking at similar issue with dynamic data fetch and how to do addition in same list item. any help?

Comment: @Blasanka Hi, your solution is great but it brings an issue with Null Safety, Could you please update your answer but using Null Safety. Thanks in advance!!